# UWP System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in async method

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

I tried to modify the code from [Windows universal samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement) for BLE Advertisement and got the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`:

```
private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (!connected)
            {

                StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
                commandFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("command_to.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                resultFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("result_from.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                BasicProperties fileProperties = await commandFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync(); //Here I get the COMException
                commandFileVersion = fileProperties.DateModified;

            }
        }
```

This method fires every time I get BLE Advertisement. And almost every time it works fine, but sometimes I get `COMException` on `GetBasicPropertiesAsync()`.

The whole Exception message:

```
-       $exception  {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000000E): A method was called at an unexpected time.

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at g831ble.MainPage.<OnAdvertisementReceived>d__10.MoveNext()}   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Comment: Try used Task instead of void

Comment: This error can happen if you have your file open for writing. You can try to properly dispose your file/stream explicitly when you no longer need them.